# Azure Powershell Port

Tags: powershell, azure

We have a VM that has restrictive internet access to the datacenter we host all our Azure Resources on (Say West US for Example) which is trying to run a command (automation) using powershell

The IPs opened were from the Microsoft reference for our particular Datacenter http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653

Because of the restrictive access,I was able to install the Powershell commandlets 0.8.8 from Github https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/releases

Whenever I try to run a specific PoSH command it fails

```
PS C:\Users\ncsa> Get-AzureSubscription | Select-AzureSubscription


Id          : Masked

Name        : RBXEnv

Environment : AzureCloud

Account     : Masked

Properties  : {}



PS C:\Users\nsalgar> Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServer

WARNING: Client Session Id: 'b75d4a4a-0964-40d0-b696-4c94992c22e6-2014-09-18 20:53:05Z'

WARNING: Client Request Id: '0305e7d5-7e50-4089-a2f2-3390130cf8b6-2014-09-18 21:01:42Z'

Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServer : **An error occurred while sending the request.**
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServer
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServer], HttpRequestException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.SqlDatabase.Server.Cmdlet.GetAzureSqlDatabaseServer
```

When I run the same from my desktop it works just fine coz there are no Internet restrictions

Can some one tell me IP Range / Ports the Windows Azure Powershell uses

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you have set the Azure SQL Database to allow connections from other Azure resources (it's an option on the firewall settings page for Azure SQL Database).

Comment: I do have ports open from there. I can connect to SQL Database via ADO.Net and SQL DataSync

Answer (score 0):

You might want to validate port 1433 is open outbound.  My organization was blocking outbound 1433 since 2005 when the slammer worm was going around.  There are a couple ways to test.  The easiest is to `telnet <dbservername> 1433` if you get a blank cmd window you are in.  You can also download NMap to do a quick port scan.